# Using a Delegate with Messages

Tags: delegates, message, max, minimum

I'm learning about delegates and think I may have found a use for one.  Basically what I have is a series of string properties that take in a minimum value and a maximum value, like so:

```
string weightInvalid(min as int32, max as int32)
```

There are several messages like this, all with unique messages but all sharing the same signature of minimum and maximum.  I think that a delegate could be used here, but how would I go about doing so?  It would really help me to see some code so I could get a grasp on this delegate stuff.

Comment: C# preferably but I'm multilingual :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple Console application example that may help...

```
public delegate string foo(int min, int max);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallFoo(foo1);
            CallFoo(foo2);
            CallFoo(foo3);

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void CallFoo(foo foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo(1, 2));
        }

        private static string foo1(int min, int max)
        {
            return "foo1";
        }

        private static string foo2(int min, int max)
        {
            return "foo2";
        }

        private static string foo3(int min, int max)
        {
            return "foo3";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've managed to implement this.  I just needed to get a picture of exactly how something like this would work.  However, I'm still confused as to why this would be useful.  Is this a practical use for something like I'm wanting to do?

Answer (score 0):

on c#:

```
delegate string weightInvalid(int min, int max);

string MyWeightInvalid(int min, int max)
{
    return "";
}

string SomeMethod()
{

    weightInvalid myFunc = new weightInvalid(MyWeightInvalid);
    return myFunc(0, 1);
}
```